# Neo4J - Aggregating data

Tags: xml, neo4j

I have inherited a codebase that uses recursive Neo4J v1.9.4 cyphers to extract data from XML files and store them 'as is' in a Neo4J database.

I need to extract and aggregate data from this Neo4J database using Cyphers and I have a question relating to the aggregation of data from within specific fields.

The XML data structure below provides an accurate representation of what is stored in the Neo4J database:

```
<description type="1">
 <narrative>
 General activity description text. Long description of the activity with no particular structure.
 </narrative>
 <narrative xml:lang="fr">
Activité générale du texte de description. Longue description de l'activité sans structure particulière.
 </narrative>
</description>
<description type="2">
 <narrative>
 Objectives for the activity, for example from a logical framework.
 </narrative>
 <narrative xml:lang="fr">
 Objectifs de l'activité, par exemple à partir d'un cadre logique.
 </narrative>
</description>
<description type="3">
 <narrative>
 Statement of groups targeted to benefit from the activity.
 </narrative>
 <narrative xml:lang="fr">
 Déclaration de groupes ciblés pour bénéficier de l'activité.
 </narrative>
</description>
```

I would like to create a cypher that will return the contents of the three english language narrative tags, that are held within the description tags, as one combined value - the returned data should look like this:

***General activity description text. Long description of the activity with no particular structure. Objectives for the activity, for example from a logical framework. Statement of groups targeted to benefit from the activity.***

A further complication is that the Cypher will also have to cope with the situation where there are fewer than 3 description tags. The edge case example (purely in terms of data structure, it may be fairly common) would be as follows:

```
<description>
 <narrative>
 General activity description text. Long description of the activity with no particular structure.
 </narrative>
 <narrative xml:lang="fr">
Activité générale du texte de description. Longue description de l'activité sans structure particulière.
 </narrative>
</description>
```

*Note the type=1 attribute is not manditory when there is only one description tag.

From this XML data structure, the output from the Cypher would need to be: ***General activity description text. Long description of the activity with no particular***

One final point to note is that the english language narrative XML tags may or may not contain the xml:lang="en" attribute.

I would like to extract the contents from any narrative tag that appears within the description structure which is missing the language attribute or has the value xml:lang="en".

We are slightly stuck with version 1.9.4 of Neo4J at the moment, so upgrading the database to get functionality from later versions of the product is not really an option.

The Cypher is as follows:

```
START   n=node:entities(type="iati-activity")
MATCH   n-[:`participating-org`]-o,
        n-[:`reporting-org`]-ro,
        n-[:`title`]-ti,
        n-[:transaction]-t-[:`transaction-type`]-tt,
        n-[?:description]-d,
        t-[:value]-v,
        n-[:`activity-status`]-status,
        t-[:`provider-org`]-po,
        n-[?:`recipient-country`]-country,
        n-[?:`recipient-region`]-region
WHERE   o.role  = 1
        AND HAS(o.ref) AND o.ref IN ["GB","GB-1"]     
        AND tt.code = 1
        AND HAS(po.`provider-activity-id`)
RETURN  n.`iati-identifier`?          as funded,
        ro.`narrative`                as reporting, 
        ti.`narrative`            as title,
        COALESCE(d.`narrative`?,"")   as description,
        po.`provider-activity-id`     as funding,
        COALESCE(v.currency?, "GBP")    as currency,
        SUM(v.value)                  as funds,
        status.code?               as status,
        COALESCE(country.code?,region.code?,"")   as recipient
```

This Cypher returns a data set in which each of the three descriptions are allocated to both recipient countries and so there are six rows of returned data.

| funded | reporting          | title                  | description                                                                                              | funding     | currency | funds | status | recipient |

| AA-AAA-123456789-ABC123 | Nom de l'organisme | Título de la actividad | Déclaration de groupes ciblés pour bénéficier de l'activité.                                             | GB-1-202035 | EUR      | 2000  | 2      | AG        |

| AA-AAA-123456789-ABC123 | Nom de l'organisme | Título de la actividad | Déclaration de groupes ciblés pour bénéficier de l'activité.                                             | GB-1-202035 | EUR      | 2000  | 2      | AF        |

| AA-AAA-123456789-ABC123 | Nom de l'organisme | Título de la actividad | Activité générale du texte de description. Longue description de l'activité sans structure particulière. | GB-1-202035 | EUR      | 2000  | 2      | AG        |

| AA-AAA-123456789-ABC123 | Nom de l'organisme | Título de la actividad | Objectifs de l'activité, par exemple à partir d'un cadre logique.                                        | GB-1-202035 | EUR      | 2000  | 2      | AG        |

| AA-AAA-123456789-ABC123 | Nom de l'organisme | Título de la actividad | Activité générale du texte de description. Longue description de l'activité sans structure particulière. | GB-1-202035 | EUR      | 2000  | 2      | AF        |

| AA-AAA-123456789-ABC123 | Nom de l'organisme | Título de la actividad | Objectifs de l'activité, par exemple à partir d'un cadre logique.                                        | GB-1-202035 | EUR      | 2000  | 2      | AF        |

I would like an amalgamated description (containing three description narratives added together) against two returned lines of recipient country data. Thank you in advance for any assistance that you are able to provide.

**Update:** I have been able to create the following Cypher which aggregates the data into two lines however the Aggregated Description field contains duplicate values (i.e. all six descriptions have been aggregated into the Aggregated Description field when I would only like to see the three unique descriptions aggregated).

```
START   n=node:entities(type="iati-activity")
MATCH   n-[:`participating-org`]-o,
        n-[:`reporting-org`]-ro,
        n-[:`title`]-ti,
        n-[:transaction]-t-[:`transaction-type`]-tt,
        n-[?:description]-d,
        t-[:value]-v,
        n-[:`activity-status`]-status,
        t-[:`provider-org`]-po,
        n-[?:`recipient-country`]-country,
        n-[?:`recipient-region`]-region
WHERE   o.role  = 1
        AND HAS(o.ref) AND o.ref IN ["GB","GB-1"]     
        AND tt.code = 1
        AND HAS(po.`provider-activity-id`)
WITH    n as n, ro as ro, ti as ti, po as po, status as status, v as v, 
        country as country, region as region, COALESCE(d.`narrative`, "") as someText           
RETURN  n.`iati-identifier`?          as funded,
        ro.`narrative`                as reporting, 
        ti.`narrative`            as title,
        REDUCE(accum = "", txt IN collect(someText) | accum + txt + " ") AS AggregatedDescription,
        po.`provider-activity-id`     as funding,
        COALESCE(v.currency?, "GBP")    as currency,
        SUM(v.value)                  as funds,
        status.code?               as status,
        COALESCE(country.code?,region.code?,"")   as recipient
```

Output data

| funded | reporting | title | AggregatedDescription | funding | currency | funds | status | recipient |

| AA-AAA-123456789-ABC123 | Nom de l'organisme | Título de la actividad | Déclaration de groupes ciblés pour bénéficier de l'activité. Objectifs de l'activité, par exemple à partir d'un cadre logique. Activité générale du texte de description. Longue description de l'activité sans structure particulière. Déclaration de groupes ciblés pour bénéficier de l'activité. Objectifs de l'activité, par exemple à partir d'un cadre logique. Activité générale du texte de description. Longue description de l'activité sans structure particulière. | GB-1-202035 | EUR | 6000 | 2 | AG |

| AA-AAA-123456789-ABC123 | Nom de l'organisme | Título de la actividad | Déclaration de groupes ciblés pour bénéficier de l'activité. Objectifs de l'activité, par exemple à partir d'un cadre logique. Activité générale du texte de description. Longue description de l'activité sans structure particulière. Déclaration de groupes ciblés pour bénéficier de l'activité. Objectifs de l'activité, par exemple à partir d'un cadre logique. Activité générale du texte de description. Longue description de l'activité sans structure particulière. | GB-1-202035 | EUR | 6000 | 2 | AF |

I have tried to use the Distinct command in conjunction with the Coalesce command so that only unique description rows were aggregated but this did not work.

Comment: You say you've inherited a code base that extracts data from XML into Neo4J.  Your query sounds totally doable, but you need to show us an example of what your neo4j data looks like.  We can't help you with a cypher query against raw XML, because it would depend on what that data looks like once it's in neo4j.  So for that XML example, can you post an equivalent neo4j data example?  Or alternatively, are you asking *how* to pull the data out of XML into neo4j?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment. I think to clarify I am asking how I could get all of the text that I have highlighted in bold into a field in a Neo4J data blob called description. I have gotten stuck with what needs to be put in the where clause, the XML source data has become more complicated and the COALESCE function that we were using is not fit for purpose (it was only used to mitigate against null values). Sorry I can't provide more details the query is saved on my desktop work machine and I'm in the UK, If you need more info I will post the query tomorrow.

Comment: You need to post what cypher you're working with, or something about how you're doing the XML data extract.  Right now, you've provided only XML details.  This tells us what you're starting with, but not what else you're working with. Your question sounds answerable with more information though.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your guidance. I oversimplified my description of the process in my initial post, we use a recursive cypher to put all of the XML data into the Neo4J database 'as is' and then using further cyphers to interrogate & aggregate this data.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question to include Cyphers and data table examples, I would greatly appreciate any advice you might be able to give as to how I can improve my Cypher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so your first question:

> I would like to create a cypher that will return the contents of the
>   three english language narrative tags, that are held within the
>   description tags, as one combined value - the returned data should
>   look like this:
>
> General activity description text. Long description of the activity
>   with no particular structure. Objectives for the activity, for example
>   from a logical framework. Statement of groups targeted to benefit from
>   the activity.

As far as I can understand, this boils down to how to concatenate multiple string values; you have three "descriptions", and you want them combined into one string:

```
START   n=node:entities(type="iati-activity")
MATCH   n-[?:description]-d
WITH    coalesce(d.narrative, "") as someText
RETURN  REDUCE(accum = "", txt IN collect(someText) | accum + txt + " ") AS joinedText;
```

So we're coalescing the text to get rid of missing values and nulls, then `REDUCE` is basically doing a string join, with `" "` as a delimiter and returning the result.

```
One final point to note is that the english language narrative XML tags may or may not contain the xml:lang="en" attribute.
```

OK so to your broader question - you might want to filter by the language in some cases, that's just a `WHERE` clause that references `d.lang` I suppose, although I can't tell from your cypher how you're storing the `lang` attribute from XML in your neo4j.

On ordering, from what you've presented, I can't tell if you're storing the original ordering of the XML tags in your cypher in any way.  You can of course order the results of the query, so if you have some sequence number in your neo4j data that preserves the original XML ordering, this is doable, but I can't give you that query as you haven't provided enough details.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, the Cypher provided did the job perfectly. I actually split my original Cypher into two parts so that I would get an aggregated description for each 'iati-identifier' and used Scala code to coalesce the results into the final object that was needed.

Comment: I think concatenating string values or "join string by token" ought to be some kind of recipe, it's a pretty common need.  Glad this helped.